# React Native simple CRUD: how to make a page rerender when coming back from a detail page

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm new to `ReactNative` and `React` and there is a thing I don't understand: how to make an already navigated page re-render when a child page changes its state. Let me explain better:

I implemented these components/pages:

- `ProfilesPage`: a page with a `FlatList` with some profiles (name, surname...). Also with a BottomSheet popup here you can create a new profile or delete one.
- `ProfileDetailPage`: when you select a single Profile from the `ProfilesPage`, it navigates here. In this page you can edit the profile's name and surname or delete it.

In the `ProfilesPage` everything works fine: I got the profiles array from my repository implementation and everytime a new profile is added or delete, I just use `setState` to rerender the whole page.

The problem comes when I am in the `ProfileDetailPage`: if a edit a profile detail name or surname or delete it and **navigate back** to the `ProfilesPage`, **the page won't rerender**!

---

My questions are:

1. Is it true that by design when a page is re navigated it won't rerender?
2. Is there an hook to force rerender when the page is navigated? I tried the following behavior but I'm not happy with it because the changes are applied after the transition animation and you clearly see that content is update.

---

What I've tried (related to question 2)

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
        console.log('FOCUS');
        setRefresh(previousState => !previousState); // To force re-render
        setCurrentProfiles(ProfilesRepository.getAllProfiles());
    });

    return unsubscribe;
}, [props.navigation]);
```

3. Is `Redux` or another state management library what I'm searching for? It seems that it has hooks to rerender each page when the state changes.
4. How to do what I want **without** another library? It seems that Redux puts a lot of boilerplate.

---

My code:

`ProfilesRepository` (Note that I keep profiles array cached, I don't see why I should re get it from the `AsyncStorage` everytime)

```
const initializeAsync = async () => {
    if (!profiles) {
        const profilesRaw = await AsyncStorage.getItem(profilesKey);
        if (profilesRaw) {
            profiles = JSON.parse(profilesRaw).map((p) =>
                Object.assign(new Profile(), p)
            );
        } else {
            profiles = Array<Profile>();
        }
    }
};

let profiles: Array<Profile> | null = null;
initializeAsync();

export const getAllProfiles = (): Profile[] => {
    return profiles!;
};

export const getProfileById = (profileId: number): Profile | undefined => {
    return profiles!.find((p) => p.id === profileId);
};

export const deleteProfileById = async (profileId: number) => {
    const profileToDelete = profiles!.find((p) => p.id === profileId);
    profiles = profiles!.filter((item) => item !== profileToDelete);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(profilesKey, JSON.stringify(profiles));
};
```

---

`ProfilesPage`

```
const ProfilesPage = (props) => {
    const [currentProfiles, setCurrentProfiles] = React.useState(
        // Pass only the function without calling it to use the lazy init overload
        // This is because otherwise everytime the bottomPopup does something, it redo getAllProfiles
        ProfilesRepository.getAllProfiles
    );

    const [refresh, setRefresh] = React.useState(false);

    // I need this to re-render the profiles list when coming back from a view
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            console.log('FOCUS');
            setRefresh(previousState => !previousState); // To force re-render
            setCurrentProfiles(ProfilesRepository.getAllProfiles());
        });

        return unsubscribe;
    }, [props.navigation]);

    const [currentSelectedProfile, setCurrentSelectedProfile] =
        React.useState<Profile>();

    const onDeleteSelectedProfileHandler = async () => {
        await ProfilesRepository.deleteProfileById(
            currentSelectedProfile!.id
        );
        setCurrentProfiles(ProfilesRepository.getAllProfiles());
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <FlatList
                data={currentProfiles}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
                renderItem={renderProfileItem}
            />

    // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `useEffect`, just use `useFocusEffect`

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

 useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => {
    setCurrentProfiles(ProfilesRepository.getAllProfiles());
}, []));
```

Comment: Thanks @Hagari! I tried, but i renders with a delay as with useEffect! I seems it does the rendering after the navigation animation ends.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved simply through `redux`. Examples corresponding to this are as follows.

[useSelector Example](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector-examples)

To solve the current problem without using `redux`, you must bring the modified profile data.

```js
//Repository.js
export const getAllProfiles = async (): Profile[] => {
    await initializeAsync();
    return profiles!;
};
//ProfilePage.js
const [currentProfiles, setCurrentProfiles] = React.useState([]);
...
useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
              ProfilesRepository.getAllProfiles().then(res => setCurrentProfiles(res))
        });

        return unsubscribe;
    }, [props.navigation]);
```

Comment: Thanks @hong! I tried the second option, but i renders with a delay, It seems it does the rendering after the navigation animation ends. I will try with useSelector!

Comment: @FrancescoBonizzi
 If you want to change it right away, you have no choice but to use the global status value.